# Allow countries keeps resetting and allowing all on frontend?

Tags: admin, address, shipping-address, customer-address

Really sorry if this has been answered elsewhere or before, but I have searched everywhere I can think of using every combination of keywords and can't seem to find a solution to my problem.

I  did find someone asking the same question on Magento's forums, but it was never solved (http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards%20/viewthread/308501/)

Anyway I'm creating a store in Magento CE 1.8.1, which basically I want to only allow people to use the United Kingdom for their billing and shipping addresses. When I set System > Configuration > General > Countries Options > Allow Countries: to just the United Kingdom this works perfectly - i.e. on all checkout combinations whether guest, register or existing member, the only option under country for any address is United Kingdom.

However I then place a few test orders through the front end of the site, and then suddenly, seemingly at random during one of the orders the country drop-down will be back to default and from then on all address input forms will show all countries for selection.

Does anybody know why this might be or what steps I can take to track down why this is happening? When I go back into the admin the Allow Countries option seems to still be just on United Kingdom. However if I unselect it, reselect it, flush the cache and reindex then the behaviour of the country drop-down is back exactly as I want it again (i.e. just the United Kingdom).

I'm using the 1 page checkout and Ultimo theme. I've modified some aspects of the fontend templates, but nothing major, and have not modified anything in the backend/core. I have 5 extensions installed if that makes any difference: Magento Color Picker for Products by Orange35, Mass Product Relater by Iksanika, Contacts Form Captcha by Oleg_Koval, Fooman Same Order Invoice Number and Orders Eraser by Wyomind.

Thanks in advance for any help anyone can offer.

Comment: see my answer here: http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/43961/231

Answer (score 0):

I'm having(had) the same situation with Magento CE 1.9.

a) You could write some tiny JS to delete the entries from the drop-down menu. That wouldn't be very aesthetic but efficient. (this will always work)

b) Try to configure allowed countries via local.xml / config.xml like this

```
<config> 
<default>
    <general>
        <country>
            <allow>DE,AT,BE,DK,FR,LI,MC,NL,PL,CH</allow>
        </country>
    </general>
 </default>
```

c) Try to set it programmatically via install script in your own module / any php.

```
$config = Mage::getModel('core/config');
$config->saveConfig('general/country/allow',"DE,AT,BE,DK,FR,LI,MC,NL,PL,CH",'default',0);
```

Flush Cache and see what happens.

Showing all countries in cart as delivery destination is a real pain for customers and can hurt your conversions, while making an unprofessional impression on customers. The whole shipping selection is a bit cumbersome and there are some nice ways of making it more user friendly.

And be aware that country of manufacture is depended on allowed countries. It will display no, if you disallow that country for shipping. That seems some real misconception on that one.